# Don't Go.. Please

Tags: wordplay, rebus

I went away. :(

I came back. :)

I went away. :(

I came back. :)

I went away. :(

I came back. :)

I went away. :(

I came back. :)

I went away. :(

I came back. :)

Hint

> It's a Rebus.

EDIT-

> This ISN'T a lateral thinking problem or a riddle. Also the Smile emoticons hold significance. It's a phrase, that's why tagged under rebus.

Comment: Are you sure it's a rebus? coz [tag:rebus] tag says "A wordplay puzzle that involves trying to figure out a word or phrase **from an image** that gives clues to parts of the word or phrase."... and I see no image.

Comment: @manshu A rebus need not be an IMAGE but even a formation of words in such a way that it can give a meaningful phrase.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus) says that it's detecting a message from a picture. You should consider using the [tag:wordplay] tag that people usually use for puzzles that are based on only words written.

Comment: @manshu Alright. I have added the tag. Thanks and keep coming back :)

Comment: I can't help but think of this animation: http://imgur.com/7RPqFJK

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since it keeps coming back with smiles, here's another guess:

> [Many happy returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many_happy_returns_%28greeting%29).

---

Previous attempt:

Based on the emoti(c)ons and movements, how about

> Come and go as you please.

Comment: try again.. smile emoticons are a giveaway

Comment: @Prashant Ok, How's the new guess?

Comment: Bull's Eye. That's perfect ;)

Answer (score 7):

Based on the brackets that make up the smiley / frowny faces:

> A sine wave:
>  [image: Sine wave diagram]

Comment: It is a phrase.. But nice try

Comment: I'll give you a nice try >:-( ... oh wait I did XD!!!!

Answer (score 6):

In a parallel universe it could be:

> A "tennis" game.

I see:

> "10 eyes" going back and forth.
>  10 Is on the left and 10 (pairs of) eyes on the right.

Comment: It may be the correct answer in a parallel universe.. Not in ours :)

Comment: This one is really creative.

Answer (score 5):

Or could be a

> boomerang

maybe?

Comment: nope.. A phrase

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is

> **FOR EVERY ACTION, THERE IS AN EQUAL AND OPPOSITE REACTION**

Reason

> I went away and I came back are actions. And for all those action there is a reaction (expression can also be considered as reaction) in the form of a smilie which are equal and opposite (sad and happy)

Comment: This may be taken as an alternate answer since you have a plausible explanation

Answer (score 3):

To me it suggests

> A Yoyo. It keeps going away and coming back on opposite sides of the string. Of course the string isn't usually curved. Maybe he's doing some kind of trick.

Comment: Nope! But I like your answer.

Answer (score 3):

To my eyes...

> The smiley-faces [now turn your head sideways...] could be depicting 2 people (the 2 dots) jumping on a trampoline (the smile). 
> Sad = the 2 jumping **up and away** from the trampoline,
> Smiley = 2 landing (**coming back down**) to the trampoline.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is not the intended answer...confirmed by OP

It can be something about

> Buses or trains that leaves the station and comes back. Maybe that's its a re**bus**.

Comment: The smile emoticons are a giveaway.. I'm looking for a phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a:

> Blinking SIgN?

Because:

> It goes away and comes back and the smiley faces and frownie faces make a SIN wave

If so:

> it may be a lateral thinking problem as well. Or dare I say vertical... ;)

Comment: It's Not a riddle.. A rebus to get a phrase out of it ;)